# NoSuchElementError... Trying to select the first child element of many

Tags: css, selenium, protractor

Error Message = 
`NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator`

There's a `button` element which has several children, amongst them a series of `p` tags.

Some Context on what the `HTML` looks like

```
<button id="SingleLander-123">
  <div>
    <div>
     <p class="someClass">This I want to access</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p class="someOtherClass">This I don't want to access</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p class="someOtherClass">This I don't want to access</p>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</button>
```

The `button` has an `id` that is called `SingleLander` + a number that is automatically generated.
The `p` has a class that is based on its current phase, amongst all the `p` children of the `button`, there is only one type of the class. But other `p` children of their respective`buttons`can have the same class.

What I want is to check whether the **Text** of the `p` tag is the same as on another page.

Here's my protractor code (trimmed down to the important part):

```
const url = await browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
const idFromUrl = /.+\/(\d+)/;
const urlId = url.match(idFromUrl)[1];

const closeMandateElement = element(by.id('backButton'));
await closeMandateElement.click();


const selectMandateStatusFromSameMandate = element.all(by.css(`#SingleLander-${urlId} div div p`)).first();

browser.sleep(5000);

const getSameMandate = element(by.id(`SingleLander-${urlId}`));
browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(getSameMandate), 5000, 'getSameMandate taking too long to appear');
await getSameMandate.click();

const textFromBubblePhase = element(by.className('1.INSTANZ'));

expect(selectMandateStatusFromSameMandate.getText()).toEqual(textFromBubblePhase);
```

The error is coming from `selectMandateStatusFromSameMandate`.

Comment: Have you checked that the DOM structure actually is what you think it was? Because that is invalid HTML - the content model for `button` is phrasing content, and that does not include `div` or `p`. So it _might_ be that a browser’s error correction builds a different DOM from this, than you were expecting.

Comment: I checked the DOM structure, again on the app itself and on the browser selenium opens. It seems to me that it is identical to what I described. However, I do get what you mean...

Comment: Check whether the element present inside an iframe?

Comment: did you make sure that `urlId` is returning the expected value?

Comment: Upload if possible the HTML of the whole page in order to practise on that and check what's wrong.

Comment: @KunduK there are no iFrames on the app

Comment: @JoaquinCasco In a separate test case I tested the ```urlId```, it does return the expected condition (leading to the respective page)

Comment: maybe try locating the button first, then the p withing that element, like this: `const button = element(by.id('SingleLander-${urlId}'));` > then: `const pButton = button.all(by.css('div div p'));` (Since the id will be unique, you dont need to specify the index)

Comment: @JoaquinCasco Ok I'll try that

Comment: `sleep` and `wait` don't work without `await`